# HMAC SHA256 does not generate the expected Hash Paw 2.2.2 when backslash character is used

Tags: paw-app

i'm testing the Paw app, it is awesome. The developer did an outstanding work, it seems that he truly loves his app.

I found that the HMAC Sha256 Crypto function doesn't returns the expected hash when the Input includes a backslash character or combinations that uses it "\n" (without quotes).

Example:

input: `GET\n/test/api`

key: `BE8B3551-1892-4544-9FDC-EC0B2C8608F8`

**Result:** `f9VF6Sy0oq645lKRcXF3N96aPZLy8qhwrbJconOJhEI=`

**Expected:** `VciY9BUCzL3KUUvFtmcRSuP2N5IkQ2gLvjjYgd3T9Uc=`

I'm generating the correct hash for the API that i'm testing using the next javascript code, which is based in the CryptoJS script:

```js
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha256.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>

<script>
    var message = 'GET\n/test/api';
var key = 'BE8B3551-1892-4544-9FDC-EC0B2C8608F8';
  var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(message, key);
  var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
document.write(hashInBase64);
</script>
```

```html
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha256.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that Paw interprets your `\n` string has actually the character `\` followed by the character `n` and not a newline character.

What you can do is to insert an actual newline by pressing Option/Alt + Enter. *(The field will have a visual glitch, and you'll only be able to see one line at a time, but the result will be correct)*

[image: HMAC-256 Signature with Paw]

Comment: Thank you very much Micha, i understand now. In the meantime, i solved the situation by running a Javascript function as a custom extension. Your program is awesome. I sent you an e-mail to for buying you app.