# How can I add a line break in a POST param value?

Tags: paw-app

I'm trying to submit a POST request using "Form Url-Encoded" params. When the value contains empty spaces, PAW encodes with the "+" sigh correctly. But what about line breaks?

How can I put a line break in a parameter value? It's a parameter in the body of the post request.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting in `%0D%0A`, which is the URL-Encoded representation of the line feed and carriage return characters, wherever you want a line break.

Comment: It doesn't work as Paw is re-encoding all the characters again.

Comment: Try pressing `option`+`return` or `control`+`return`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866785/hmac-sha256-does-not-generate-the-expected-hash-paw-2-2-2-when-backslash-charact/31879022#31879022)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably to add that as a Custom Dynamic Value (right-click and pick from the menu: Extensions > Custom). And just returns a `"\n"` from JavaScript.

He's how it should be looking like:

[image: Paw add a newline]

The JavaScript code is:

```
function evaluate(context){
  return "\n";
};
```

That should do the trick.